# Does HTTP/2 support sending binary messages?

Tags: http2

For an example, one can send binary data as either a Blob or an ArrayBuffer using WebSockets.

```js
var file = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').files[0];
connection.send(file);
```

Currently server sent events (SSE) don't have the binary messaging capability. 
Can I know HTTP/2 protocol supports for sending binary messages? (References would be better)